# Rails: How can I get the new action to work in a pop up as opposed to a new page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When a user clicks on Send Message, I'd like a pop-up box to appear which has the send message form in it. The User can write a msg and hit send. The pop-up part is easy and I have it implemented through jquery. But how do I get the new action to work in it? In other words, when a user clicks on Send Message, I'd like in to be linked to the new action, but instead of going to the new view on a separate page, I'd like the new view to be a pop-up

Comment: try searching for ajax and jquery dialog boxes then come back here when you get stuck while trying to implement what you need to do.

Comment: google -> $.ajax.  Then google respond_to json rails.  That will get you the answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make most links, buttons or forms remote by adding `:remote => true` to the tag, this will allow the controller to respond with a .js file instead of .html.

In this js file you can use jquery to show the popup box, probably using the logic you've already implemented.